# SQL Multiple select from same table

Tags: sql-server

I have a Transactions table that includes three columns: transactionType, amount and transactionTimestamp. The transactionType column accepts values of 1 (cash), 2 (checks) or 3 (credit cards).

I need to show the total amount of each transactionType per day. I can do this using separate queries for each transactionType easily:

```
    SELECT SUM(amount) AS cashTotal, dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(DAY, 0, transactionTimestamp)) AS transactionDay
    FROM TransactionRecords
    WHERE transactionType = 1
    GROUP BY dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(DAY, 0, transactionTimestamp));

    SELECT SUM(amount) AS checkTotal, dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(DAY, 0, transactionTimestamp)) AS transactionDay
    FROM TransactionRecords
    WHERE transactionType = 2
    GROUP BY dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(DAY, 0, transactionTimestamp));

    SELECT SUM(amount) AS cardTotal, dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(DAY, 0, transactionTimestamp)) AS transactionDay
    FROM TransactionRecords
    WHERE transactionType = 3
    GROUP BY dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(DAY, 0, transactionTimestamp));
```

But what I need to do is to do it in one query. I've tried combining the above into one as below:

```
SELECT 
        (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM TransactionRecords WHERE transactionType = 1 GROUP BY dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(DAY, 0, transactionTimestamp))) AS cashTotal, 
        (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM TransactionRecords WHERE transactionType = 2 GROUP BY dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(DAY, 0, transactionTimestamp))) AS checkTotal,
        (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM TransactionRecords WHERE transactionType = 3 GROUP BY dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(DAY, 0, transactionTimestamp))) AS cardTotal,
        dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(DAY, 0, transactionTimestamp)) AS transactionDay
    FROM TransactionRecords
    GROUP BY dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(DAY, 0, transactionTimestamp));
```

But this only results in a "Subquery returned more than 1 value" error. And I get the feeling that's not how it should be done anyway. Thanks for any advice.

EDIT: I should clarify a bit that I'm trying to output results like the following:

```
----------------------------------------------------
cashTotal | checkTotal | cardTotal | transactionDay
----------------------------------------------------
1000      | 1000        | 1000      | date
0         | 500         | 0         | date
----------------------------------------------------
```

Each row shows the total amount of each transactionType for that particular day.

EDIT: Some details edited to remove sensitive information.

Comment: Why don't you use `CASE..WHEN`?

Comment: Are you looking for a `UNION`?

Comment: Kindly do not vandalize or deface your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation with `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
SELECT 
        SUM(CASE WHEN paymentType = 1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as cashTotal,
        SUM(CASE WHEN paymentType = 2 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as chequeTotal,
        SUM(CASE WHEN paymentType = 3 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as cardTotal,
        dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(DAY, 0, transactionTimestamp)) AS transactionDay
    FROM PaymentRecords
    GROUP BY dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(DAY, 0, transactionTimestamp));
```

Although this row seems weird

```
dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(DAY, 0, transactionTimestamp))
```

Did you mean to trunc the datetime? If so replace this with:

```
CAST(transactionTimestamp as DATE)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice, but I'm curious to know how to get to ELSE 0, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I mean in what situation does the SUM use the 0 instead of the amount. I've found an answer here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120003/what-does-then-1-else-0-mean-in-a-case-expression-used-with-an-aggregate-functio but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: Yea this pretty much explain it perfectly:) . @Alycus

Answer (score 1):

So you want top simply group by paymentType as well?

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS cashTotal
     , paymentType
     , dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(DAY, 0, transactionTimestamp)) AS transactionDay
FROM PaymentRecords
GROUP BY paymentType
       , dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(DAY, 0, transactionTimestamp));
```

You can add an `ORDER BY` to get the items in the order you want (by type, then date, or vice versa)

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation.  Also, you can convert to `date` to remove the time component of a date:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN transactionType = 1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as cashTotal, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN transactionType = 2 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as checkTotal, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN transactionType = 3 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as cardTotal,
       CAST(transactionTimestamp as DATE) as TransactionDay
FROM TransactionRecords
GROUP BY CAST(transactionTimestamp as DATE)
ORDER BY CAST(transactionTimestamp as DATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your approach last line `"GROUP BY dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(DAY, 0, transactionTimestamp));` is not required I guess..

ALso looks like you just need to group by Paymentype and transcation day.. something like

`Select sum(amnt),payment_type,transactionDay from PaymentRecords group by payment_type,transactionDay`

Note : Format the transactionDay according to ur need.